# Write Output List to File

Tags: python, io

I'm trying to write an output list to a file, but only getting the last line from the list to actually write to the file.  How can I change my code so that it captures everything?

```
import os

slices = [(0,3), (12,28), (29,31), (32,33), (34,38), (130,144), (39,41), (32,33), (42,55), (58,64), (65,72), (73,74), (75,78), (79,84), (99,102)]
File = r"E:\file.txt"
outfile = r"E:\file_output.txt"

with open(File) as sourcefile:

for line in sourcefile: 
    result = [line[slice(*slc)] for slc in slices]

myfile = open(outfile, 'w')

for lines in result:
    myfile.write("%s\t" % lines)

myfile.close()
```

Comment: Your indentation seems a bit off.  Could you go in and take another look at it?

Comment: @user1457123 if my answer helped, it's good etiquette to accept by clicking the check mark next to my answer. It gives you reputation too! If not, let me know that something's still wrong and I can try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is re-assigning `result` each iteration. Therefore, at the end of the loop `result` still only has one list in it. Assign `myfile` before the loop, and put the `myfile.write` statement inside the loop.

```
myfile = open(outfile, 'w')
for line in sourcefile: 
    result = [line[slice(*slc)] for slc in slices]
    myfile.write("%s\t" % result)
```

Alternatively, if you want to have a list of all the results, you can use `+=` to get a list of lists, as in

```
result += [line[slice(*slc)] for slc in slices]
```

Comment: Rob, thanks for educating me on what I was doing wrong.  I'm a newb at this as you can probably tell.  Your solution ran correctly except now I have to figure out how to remove the single quotes and brackets form the output file (i.e. ['004', .....).  My goal is to have a delimited output file after the slicing has occured.  Any ideas?

Comment: I need the output that looks like this: ['001', 'Bla Bla     ', 'Bla', '6', 'Bla', 'Bla Bla       ', '  ', '6', '             ', '125489', '125489', '1', '001', 'B7542', '   '] to look like this: 001, Bla Bla     , Bla, 6, Bla, Bla Bla       ,   , 6,              , 125489, 125489, 1, 001, B7542,

Comment: I think that got it. I had to format it liek this in order to create a new line when needed: myfile.write(', '.join(result)+"\n")

Comment: Looks right. Conventionally, you might want to put the newline at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you iterate inside the "for line in sourcefile" block, you are overwriting the "result" list. That's why you end up with only the final line stored in "result"

To solve this, you can extend your list comprehension and remove the for loop altogether:

```
result = [line[slice(*slc) for slc in slices for line in sourcefile]
```